# Which the faster method to download and save image from external link using Php?

Tags: php

I need to  download and store the image into my local sever from external link .

Now I wrote the cron function  did the job . And also ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

```
I used curl method for download the image from external link. And, fwrite was used 

to save the image into my local server . I  need to know which method is faster ?

Like (fileputcontents,fwrite,copy)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do as below:

```
$from_url = "yoursiteurl";
$path = "pathtofolder";
$file_name = "latest.zip";
file_put_contents($path.$file_name, file_get_contents($from_url.$file_name));
```

this is the fastest method for server to server transfer.